# Two Drawers Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, drawer

Can I have two drawers for one page in xamarin forms, I know about master details page but I need drawers on both sides left and right.
Thanks

Comment: Having created an app with two side drawers before, my advice to you is to rethink your application layout so that you don't need a second drawer. It's not a common UI design so people often have trouble accessing the second drawer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please post what have you tried so far and take a look at how to ask good questions: [ask]

Comment: Instead of using a 2nd sidemenu u could perhaps use a toolbar ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package SlideOverkit: 1- Install the nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlideOverKit/ 2- Create a new view that inherit's from SlideMenuView, then put all your UI code for the menu into this class, you can do this in XAML or code

Check the full documentation: http://www.xam-consulting.com/slideoverkit-xamarin-forms/